# Use of Perl LWP

Tags: perl, lwp

I'm creating a website which will fetch product details from different eCommerce websites and will show a comparison chart on my site. Is that possible to fetch the datas from other sites & display it on my website using Perl LWP module?

Comment: yes, it is possible.

Comment: Fetching web-accessible documents, yes. Extract the information and generate web pages from that information, no.

Comment: @ikegami Is there a way to extract the contents & write the data in to DB from the fetched data using LWP?

Comment: Is it possible to obtain the documents fetched by LWP in a variable? Of course! Is it possible to store strings in a database? Of course!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible, but the details depend heavily how the data are served by the other sites. Especially if the other sites are created with JavaScript (e.g. on the client side) it will be hard. Also, [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/WWW-Mechanize-1.73/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm) (which is a layer on top [LWP](http://search.cpan.org/~mschilli/libwww-perl-6.06/lib/LWP.pm)) might be easier to use for this task or you might have a look at [Mojo::UserAgent](http://search.cpan.org/~sri/Mojolicious-4.94/lib/Mojo/UserAgent.pm) which has a comfortable way of extracting information by using a DOM model with CSS-like specifiers.